# R: Fill in missing values by back calculation

Tags: r, na

I have received a data set in which all values below 10 have been replaced by a *. However, the data set also contains row and column totals, which partially make the back calculation possible.

For the rows I have already managed this, but for the columns I lack the inspiration how this could work.

When reading the CSV files, the * are converted to NAs, so a sample dataset looks like this:

| ID | V1 | V2 | V3 | VS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 36 |
| A2 | NA | 11 | 12 | 32 |
| A3 | NA | 12 | NA | 24 |
| AS | 27 | 35 | 32 | 92 |

In this example the NA for ID A2 should be replaced by 9 [*32 - (11 + 12)*].
The next step is to calculate the NAs for ID A3.
V1 should be replaced by 7 [*27 - (11 + 9)*] and V3 by 5 [*32 - (13 + 12)*]

I feel like this is actually one of the simplest problems, but I just can't come up with the solution. Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks a lot
Benne

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `dplyr`: I do it in two steps, 1) calculate the imputation that is performed rowwise, and 2) the column-specific imputation.

```
df <- read.table(text= "ID  V1  V2  V3  VS
A1  11  12  13  46
A2  NA  11  12  32
A3  NA  12  NA  24
AS  27  35  32  102", h = T) 


library(dplyr)
df %>%
  slice(1:2) %>% 
  mutate(across(V1:VS, ~ifelse(is.na(.x), VS - V3 - V2, .x))) %>% 
  rbind(df[3:4,1:5]) %>% 
  mutate(across(V1:VS, ~ifelse(is.na(.x), dplyr::lead(.x) - dplyr::lag(.x, 2) - dplyr::lag(.x,1), .x)))
```

*Result*:

```
  ID V1 V2 V3  VS
1 A1 11 12 13  46
2 A2  9 11 12  32
3 A3  7 12  7  24
4 AS 27 35 32 102
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

I found another solution:
I transpose the complete dataset and use the rowwise function on it.
Afterwards I transpose it back and rerun the procedure.